# Content of <div> overlapping another <div>?

Tags: css, html

I have been facing this problem that when I am adding a div, it is being overlapped on the div above it? To see where the div is being aligned, I have given it a background of blue. I want to align the hitchhiking `<h1>` tag to the center of the page below the intro div. Find the code below-

I have been facing this problem that when I am adding a div, it is being overlapped on the div above it? To see where the div is being aligned, I have given it a background of blue. Find the code below-

```css
          #intro{
             font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif; 
            font-size: 170%;    
            float: right;                   
            width: 50%;                
            margin-right: 20px;
             margin-left: 10px;
                color: #ff471a ;
            } 
            
            
            
            #introImage { 
            
                float: left;
                width: 40%;
                margin-left: 70px;
                margin-top: 35px;
                box-shadow: 10px 10px grey;
                border-radius: 10px;
            
            }
            
            
             
        
        #hitchhiking-info {
            
            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: blue;
            float: none;
            
        }
```

```html
</div> 
        
        <div id="intro-div"> 
            
            <p id="intro"> Hello There! I have made this website to share my experiences of hitchhiking, which is my full time job. I want to inspire other hitchhikers as well and inspire people. This website will hopefully clear all your misconceptions about hitchhiking as a proffession, as it is underrated and critisized by people. However I have a very different perspective about hitchhiking, you will get to know about it through my website. This website is a mean I will be using to reach to people around the world. Fell free to comment any suggestions or feedback of my experiences and contact me for any query </p>    
            
            <img id="introImage" src="intro-image.jpg">
            
            
            
            
        </div> 
        
        <div id="hitchhiking-info">
            
            <h1 id="heading"> Hitchhiking </h1>   
        </div>
```

Comment: so which div is overlapping which div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your "hitchhiking-info" box is being displayed all the way at the top is because your "intro-div" box only contains floated elements, therefore it has no height.

To push the "hitchhiking-info" div past the floated content you can apply `clear:both` to it. This will have it "clear" content that is floated left or right.

Another option would be to apply a clearfix class to your "intro-div" (or give it an explicit height so that it contains all it's floated content). Check out a simple clearfix below and read more about them [here](http://learnlayout.com/clearfix.html).

**`clear:both` Example:**

```css
#intro {
  font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
  font-size: 170%;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #ff471a;
}
#introImage {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#hitchhiking-info {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="intro-div">
  <p id="intro">Hello There! I have made this website to share my experiences of hitchhiking, which is my full time job. I want to inspire other hitchhikers as well and inspire people. This website will hopefully clear all your misconceptions about hitchhiking as a
    proffession, as it is underrated and critisized by people. However I have a very different perspective about hitchhiking, you will get to know about it through my website. This website is a mean I will be using to reach to people around the world.
    Fell free to comment any suggestions or feedback of my experiences and contact me for any query</p>
  <img id="introImage" src="intro-image.jpg">
</div>
<div id="hitchhiking-info">
  <h1 id="heading"> Hitchhiking </h1> 
</div>
```

**Clearfix Example:**

```css
#intro {
  font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif;
  font-size: 170%;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #ff471a;
}
#introImage {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 35px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#hitchhiking-info {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  float: none;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
</div>

<div id="intro-div" class="clearfix">
  <p id="intro">Hello There! I have made this website to share my experiences of hitchhiking, which is my full time job. I want to inspire other hitchhikers as well and inspire people. This website will hopefully clear all your misconceptions about hitchhiking as a
    proffession, as it is underrated and critisized by people. However I have a very different perspective about hitchhiking, you will get to know about it through my website. This website is a mean I will be using to reach to people around the world.
    Fell free to comment any suggestions or feedback of my experiences and contact me for any query</p>
  <img id="introImage" src="intro-image.jpg">
</div>
<div id="hitchhiking-info">
  <h1 id="heading"> Hitchhiking </h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: @PiyushMaheshwari of course, you are most welcome, I hope this answered your question. If it did, you can use the checkmark underneath the voting arrows to mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: hey man, another question, I just added an hr below intro div, but the hr only extends till the image, can you help me out?

Comment: @PiyushMaheshwari yes I can help, but post this question in a new stack overflow question with updated code so I can see what your exact problem is.

Answer (score 1):

```
See this its not overlapping i have changed the id # **hitchhacking-info to  float: left;**
#intro{
             font-family: 'Sansita', sans-serif; 
            font-size: 170%;    
            float: right;                   
            width: 50%;                
            margin-right: 20px;
             margin-left: 10px;
                color: #ff471a ;
            } 



            #introImage { 

                float: left;
                width: 40%;
                margin-left: 70px;
                margin-top: 35px;
                box-shadow: 10px 10px grey;
                border-radius: 10px;

            }




        #hitchhiking-info {

            margin-top: 20px;
            width: 100%; 
            height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            background-color: blue;
            float: left;

        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!, but I also have one more doubt, I added an hr below intro and intro image, however the image only extends till the image. Can you help me out

Comment: you have to add <hr/> where you want the line have answered kindly accept the answer

Comment: yeah I did the same thing, but the hr only extends till the info-image